# Scraping href links and scrape from these links

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm doing python scraping and i'm trying to get all the links between href tags and then accessing it one by one to scrape data from these links. I'm a newbie and can't figure it out how to continue from this.The code is as follows:

```
 import requests
    import urllib.request
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv

    url = 'https://menupages.com/restaurants/ny-new-york'
    url1 = 'https://menupages.com'
    response = requests.get(url)
    f = csv.writer(open('Restuarants_details.csv', 'w'))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    menu_sections=[]
    for url2 in soup.find_all('h3',class_='restaurant__title'):
    completeurl = url1+url2.a.get('href')
    print(completeurl)

    #print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape all the links obtained from the first page, and then scrape all the links obtained from these links, etc, you need a recursive function.

Here is some initial code to get you started:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    initial_url = "https://menupages.com/restaurants/ny-new-york"
    scrape(initial_url)

def scrape(url):
    print("now looking at " + url)
    # scrape URL
    # do something with the data

    if (STOP_CONDITION):  # update this!
        return

    # scrape new URLs:
    for new_url in soup.find_all(...):
        scrape(new_url, file)
```

The problem with this recursive function is that it will not stop until there are no links on the pages, which probably won't happen anytime soon. You will need to add a stop condition.